# MySql Add Index : 0 Rows Affected

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
Alter table table1 add index col1_idx (column1);
```

Even though the table1 has many rows and all of the have non null values for column1, the above query says "0 Rows AFfected". Why could this be?

Answer (score 6):

That is because the query is not directly affecting any rows as opposed to an update statement where you modify the row. It (very, very, very basically) only changes how the column is stored and sorted.

Comment: That's what I also thought but I think sometimes adding index does say 'X rows affected' where X is non-zero. Or that's never possible?