# How do I index pre-existing data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, innodb

I created an index on a MySQL innodb table that I imported data *too*.  The table was created by MySQL when the table was imported.  I did nothing.  It simply imported the data with the GUI.

Then I tried to add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX idx_myindex (some_column);
```

I always get:

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

I read this question:

[MySql Add Index : 0 Rows Affected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845197/mysql-add-index-0-rows-affected)

How do I make my table that already has data in it to index the column which actually affects the row?  I am using innoDB.

Do I need to export, delete all data, reimport (making index update)?

Comment: adding an index to a table will automatically populate that index. there's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: Why would I get zero rows affected?

Comment: because an index doesn't CHANGE any of the data in the records. indexes are metadata.

Comment: That is why I am asking the question.  How do I index pre-existing data?

Comment: And I already told you that adding an index to a table automatically populates the index. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: I understand now.  Thanks.  To me indexing is affecting the table.  MySQL means the row data is not changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 5.1 and earlier reported N rows affected when you create an index, and N was always the number of rows in the table.

Starting in MySQL 5.5.5, they stopped reporting that number, and decided that rows affected was always zero for all DDL statements. See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21818

Be assured that creating an index automatically populates it with values. You can verify this by running `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable'` before and after creating the index. One of the fields shown is `index_length`, which increases after you add a secondary index.