# 0 rows affected while adding column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, alter-table

I am using MariaDB `10.1.30`. When I run an `alter table add column` query from command line, the result was as follows:

`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

I understand why the second line looks like that, but why adding a column will result in `0 rows affected`?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it? Whether any existing rows were affected depends entirely on what the DEFAULT value of the new column was.

Comment: @EJP So if the DEFAULT value of the new column is NULL, no rows will be affected? If so, will the number of rows affected be non zero if the DEFAULT value is not NULL and there are some rows in the table?

Comment: That's what it looks like, isn't it? Why not try it? Easy enough to test with a temporary column.

Comment: @EJP I tried that, with a non NULL DEFAULT value, but it's still zero.

Comment: Because you have not modified any data (on any row), only the table's **underlying structure**. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845233/7644018).

Comment: @Paul T. But that didn't explain why it still shows zero rows affected. A non NULL DEFAULT value definitely modified some data because that creates data that doesn't exist before the query

Comment: Well, it does (to me). I believe that you are thinking WAY too far into the situation. Again, you are NOT changing any rows (data-wise), but only to the underlying table structure.  You are NOT doing an `UPDATE` nor an `INSERT`, but an `ALTER`, which does not have the same row-based handling. The `non NULL DEFAULT` only applies to NEW records, and not to what record(s) already exist.

Comment: This is one of those "Just live with it!" situations.

Answer (score 0):

This is its way of saying that the `ALTER` did not need to rebuild the table.